# Set Navigation Title color in Xamarin(Ios)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I want set navigation Bar Title color in Xamarin(Ios) using C#.

I set below way but it not work.

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f);
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = UIColor.Magenta;
```

the `BarTintColor` work but `TitleTextAttributes` not work.. I also see documentation but in document the title text color not mention.

Any help be Appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Spending 1 Hour  I got the solution.

Type `UIKit.UINavigationBar` does not contain a definition for `SetTitleTextAttributes` and no extension method `SetTitleTextAttributes` of type `UIKit.UINavigationBar` could be found. and it give below error :

> Are you missing an assembly reference ?

So Instead of calling `SetTitleTextAttributes`, do the following:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes()
        {
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
        };
```

Hope this will help other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom view as the navigation bar's title view, then you can modify it easily.

In your "ViewDidLoad" method, using this code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            //Normal way
            //this.Title = "Normal";//or this.NavigationItem.Title = "Normal;
            //Using custom view
            UILabel lbTitle = new UILabel(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 50, 30));
            lbTitle.Text = "CustomView";
            lbTitle.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
            lbTitle.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(15);
            this.NavigationItem.TitleView = lbTitle;
            //Using a picture
            //this.NavigationItem.TitleView = new UIImageView();
        }
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I try that type solution but that not work like this : `UITextAttributes myTextAttrib = new UITextAttributes();
myTextAttrib.Font = UIFont.FromName("Copperplate",24);
myTextAttrib.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(202,185,131);
myNavController.NavigationBar.SetTitleTextAttributes(myTextAttrib);`  by the way thnx for your answer but i get solution ..

Comment: UITextAttributes is not a UIView, so of course it can not work. use UILabel.

Comment: UITextAttributes is very complicated, try to use custom view. It's more convenient and you can even set an image as your navigation title.